# Is it possible to deploy web app to azure without VSCode?

Tags: azure

I see documentation on deploying app to Azure using Vscode. But is there a way to deploy without Vscode? Like some direct deployment method through the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your source code pushed to any source control in cloud, you can deploy through the [Deployment Center](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/videos/azure-friday-an-overview-of-azure-app-service-deployment-center/) or via [Azure Devops.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Dead link. Would be easier to have just said 'No'.